# Salesforce org monitoring and limits exceeding alerts

Tags: limits, alert, monitoring

I would like to understand better the possible ways to monitor proactivately a Salesforce org.
Below a list of the current alerts that are known to me:

- API Usage Notifications (standard)
- Trust status subscription (standard) in order to be alerted about service disruptions, performance degradations and maintenances
- Custom alert regarding DailyBulkAPIRequests limits

Do you happen to know any other alert that can be set - even not out of the box - or any other standard notification that is sent when limits are exceeded?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the ways mentioned by Mr.Frodo,you can also call a rest endpoint to get all these details.

[image]

Limits that you can get with this method.

- ConcurrentAsyncGetReportInstances
- ConcurrentSyncReportRuns
- DailyAnalyticsDataflowJobExecutions
- DailyApiRequests
- DailyAsyncApexExecutions
- DailyBulkApiRequests
- DailyDurableGenericStreamingApiEvents
- DailyDurableStreamingApiEvents
- DailyGenericStreamingApiEvents
- DailyStreamingApiEvents
- DailyWorkflowEmails
- DataStorageMB
- DurableStreamingApiConcurrentClients
- FileStorageMB
- HourlyAsyncReportRuns
- HourlyDashboardRefreshes
- HourlyDashboardResults
- HourlyDashboardStatuses
- HourlyODataCallout
- HourlySyncReportRuns
- HourlyTimeBasedWorkflow
- MassEmail
- Package2VersionCreates
- PermissionSets
- SingleEmail
- StreamingApiConcurrentClients

You can periodically(scheduler) call the rest endpoint and get data and manually send the notifications for limits that can near exhaustion.

Comment: But you have to be careful, because some limits (like Async Apex Executions) will block the monitoring job for going off if they're exceeded first!

Comment: Yeah..  should look for this caveats.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools salesforce provides for monitoring the limits. you can go to monitoring section in salesforce and look for System overview. System overview will give you an overall view of Limits important limits in org.

[image]

In company information section also you can check license based limits also there are some standard administrative reports available which could also be helpful. You can also create some custom administrative reports.

[image]

There is Health Checker available in your org.

[image]

There is optimizer provided.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try out leveraging Event Montoring which captures following event types and those can be report able. It comes with Salesforce Shield.

Refer [Event Monitoring](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/shield/modules/event_monitoring) trailhead and [EventLogFile Supported Event Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm)

- Apex Callout Event Type
- Apex Execution Event Type
- Apex SOAP Event Type
- Apex Trigger Event Type
- API Event Type
- Asynchronous Report Run Event Type
- Bulk API Event Type
- Change Set Operation Event Type
- Console Event Type
- Content Distribution Event Type
- Content Document Link Event Type
- Content Transfer Event Type
- Continuation Callout Summary Event Type
- Dashboard Event Type
- Document Attachment Downloads Event Type
- External Cross-Org Callout Event Type
- External Custom Apex Callout Event Type
- External OData Callout Event Type
- Insecure External Assets Event Type
- Knowledge Article View Event Type
- Lightning Error Event Type
- Lightning Interaction Event Type
- Lightning Page View Event Type
- Lightning Performance Event Type
- Login Event Type
- Login As Event Type
- Logout Event Type
- Metadata API Operation Event Type
- Multiblock Report Event Type
- Package Install Event Type
- Platform Encryption Event Type
- Queued Execution Event Type
- Report Event Type
- Report Export Event Type
- REST API Event Type
- Sandbox Event Type
- Search Event Type
- Search Click Event Type
- Sites Event Type
- Time-Based Workflow Event Type
- Transaction Security Event Type
- URI Event Type
- Visualforce Event Type
- Wave Change Event Type
- Wave Interaction Event Type
- Wave Performance Event Type

Answer (score 0):

You can use Salesforce doctor tool as well. It is a tool that inspects your salesforce org and let you know the current limits and other information via an email.